# NSwag multipart form generate Blob

Tags: .net, typescript, nswag

Endpoint which accepts multipart form data look valid in Swagger, and accepts form data from a client. However the typescript client generated by NSwag is not usable. The generated method only accept Blob.

`uploadDoc(content:Blob): Observable<void>`

I couldn't find any option related to this in NSwag

I tried search for special decorators. But I assume the client generation cause this problem, because the endpoint works from Swagger perfectly fine.

Comment: Can you share your endpoint? What form fields are you expecting? If you're expecting a single file, are you sure that `Blob` not usable?

Comment: It's a file, along with other fields. Some string, datetime, etc.. File is `string($binary)` in the code it's of type `IFormFile`.

Answer (score 0):

NSwag not support generating multipart form data client side that use Blob. This is a known issue, and [here](https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag/issues/2419) is a GitHub issue tracking it.

Comment: As far as I can see, the provided link is not about TypeScript, though I can see it's about the same subject. So a broader issue then, dating back 4 years lol.